# how show notification in onTaskComplete from this code when app closed or runnig in background

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask

this code get request from server and do some thing. i want when app is closed get request and show it by notification. i can get message from firebase and show it but this is not something that i want

## MyActivity

```
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivitiy implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .
    .
}
private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    String regId = preferenceHelper.getSessionToken();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
}
private void subscribeToPushService() {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {


}



@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(String response, int service) {
    super.onTaskCompleted(response, service);
    switch (service) {
    case MyValues.Service.REQUEST_NEW:
    //          addNotification();
    ...
        if (requestId == MyValues.NO_REQUEST) {
            addNotification();
            addNewFragment(new myFragment(), false,
                    MyValues.REQUEST_, true);
        } else {
            ...
        }
        break;
}
}
```

## ActionBarActivitiy

```
abstract public class ActionBarActivitiy extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener , AsyncTaskCompleteListener
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void addNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApplication.applicationContext)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_cl)
                    .setContentTitle("Notifications get request")
                    .setContentText("This is get request notification");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MyApplication.applicationContext, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(MyApplication.applicationContext, 0, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
 //        builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    builder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + MyApplication.applicationContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sfx_counter_loop));
 //     builder.setOngoing(true);
    try {

        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)
            MyApplication.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(String response, int service) {

}

....

}
```

## interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener
{
void onTaskCompleted(String response, int service);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use A service, An alarm manager to do so.

Schedule a timer tat will run the service. The service will fetch the data and then show the notification. You can also use IntentService for that so as to free up your main thread.

**Edit**

Here is an link for alarm manager :

```
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
```

and IntentService :

```
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html
```

Also, to call certain task before your app gets close, call your method in onStop right before calling super.

Comment: when app is not runnig how  to run onTaskCompleted??? it's my problem...

Comment: i can create service and alarm manager but i dont know where app is closed how to get request. is arrived or not in onTaskcompleted

Comment: How is your app getting request?

Comment: Your English is bit rusty and it's difficult to understand. Do you want to do some work when app gets closed?